# Wowza.GoCoder not working with org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder

Tags: android, wowza, android-ffmpeg

I am working with code from https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/blob/master/JavaCV-android-example/app/src/main/java/org/bytedeco/javacv_android_example/record/RecordActivity.java. Demo working fine

I want to use wowza.gocoder with FFmpeg so by only add wowza dependancy  in app.gradle then demo application crash at run time as screenshot

[image]

here is my app.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cygnus.ffmpegframerecorderexample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/assets']
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

ext {
    versions = [
            'ffmpeg': '3.2.1-1.3'
    ]
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'


    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.9.8'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


    //implementation 'com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.android:com.wowza.gocoder.sdk:2.0.0@aar'//sdf


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    implementation 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.1'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.5'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.6.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.0@jar'
    androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.0'


    implementation(group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets'
    }

    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.3.1'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv-platform', version: '3.1.0-1.3'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg-platform', version: '3.2.1-1.3'

    //implementation 'com.vxg.mediasdk:playersdk:2.0.140'//sdf
    implementation 'com.iceteck.silicompressorr:silicompressor:2.2.2'
}
```

Comment: Just un comment wowza library line its crash at run time.

Comment: With which part you have problem, with sample, or with third party library? Your error is pretty straight forward, there are missing native reference. But I don't sure, where is problem, because sample from https://github.com/bytedeco/sample-projects/blob/master/JavaCV-android-example doesn't have any dependencies.

Comment: @GensaGames thanks for replay as per your link demo is working fine. but I want use with wowza player or VGX Player so if I add one of library as comment in above gradle , if I un comment and run gives me above error as per screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

So finally, there is an issue, but with merging dependencies inside project. **To start first**, issue with linking native sources, and for some implementation, it's not possible to find native methods, which could be changed, because this resource get updated in scope of other library, which use latest version of it.

To make sure, it's an issue, you need to check dependencies in project with `./gradlew app:dependencies`. And double check, that something similar could be found in the `com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.android` and `org.bytedeco.*`.

And to resolve it, need to configure [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html) by changing some options for one or another library, based on their dependency tree.

Comment: I thought so you are right FFMpeg also used by wowza.gocoder but inside its sdk.
Thanks @GensaGames for replay

Comment: any idea how I apply https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html to resolve above issue ?

Comment: @HiteshGs Most simple solution, would be manually loading the `.jar` files of both libraries `com.wowza.gocoder.sdk.android` and `org.bytedeco.*` and adding it to your project.

Comment: @HiteshGs another way, it's find that conflicting library (by using `./gradlew app:dependencies` and checking duplicates libs inside both packages) and set ResolutionStrategy. But it's quite complected.

Comment: is there any way I am able to fix as per @GensaGames above hint.
if any example that help me.

Comment: any way I achieve your solution?

Comment: @HiteshGs Sorry for the delay.  I cannot fix your application in comment section. What you need to do, I just wrote above. 1. Debug conflicting dependencies. 2. Set gradle 'conflict resolution' for a specific lib.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an older platform of JavaCV. 
You must try again with JavaCV 1.5.1. 
Maybe there is something that can be fixed.

Comment: Maybe you could check, all the out of dated dependencies. :D I Don't sure it's a solution.